# Will any files or apps delete after updating to Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I'm downloading the update right now and I would like to know if any of my files or app gets deleted after this update... I'm sure many people here already installed the update so what can you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been running Mavericks for about two weeks and I haven't noticed any apps that were deleted during the install. Some of Apple's apps may be updated during the upgrade, but I'm not aware of anything that gets deleted.

Comment: Even if a backup is not carried out (although very unwise) all files, apps etc remain in place as before ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Yes. OS upgrades should not delete any thing from the apps folder. Are you worried about 3rd party apps, or apps from Apple that you haven't upgraded for some reason?

Comment: Just concerned because i've never upgraded to a newer OS.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

The upgrade to Mavericks overwrote the config file for the Apache web server (localhost). It also overwrote the environment variable giving access to Java.

Answer (score 1):

From my upgrade experience, nothing has been lost in the process. All application settings are the same, all the applications are there and all the files are still here.

Upgrading an operating system should never touch your personal information and your installed applications unless you are doing a clean install, but if you are simply running the "Install OSX Mavericks" application, you have nothing to worry about.

However, the only thing that does get deleted is the installer itself once you have finished upgrading. If you would like to keep it to either create a [bootable recovery USB](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/) or use the installer to upgrade other Macs you own, you can either copy it to a USB or some other form of storage besides your boot hard disk or simply make a copy of it in a compressed zip folder which wont be deleted regardless of its location.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the Finder favorites were reset.  I had some custom folders in the list of favorite before the update and now they are gone.  I KNOW that I had a favorite for Dropbox and it was missing after the install (I chose to move my Dropbox folder to another drive so it isn't the favorite created by Dropbox).  There was also a new favorite for "Deleted Users" that I didn't know existed before.

I tried going through time machine history to see when it changed, but it doesn't seem like the list of favorites are changed  with time machine.

Answer (score 0):

My folder favorites also disappeared after a couple restarts, and two of them moved up top as as toolbar shortcuts. I had about 30 of them for work purposes. I have not figured out how to get them back yet other than just manually re-adding them all.

Answer (score -2):

After upgrading to maverick a folder was deleted out of my dropbox.  I didn't notice it until a month later and Maverick was the only change I made to my pc so I'm blaming it.